# WPF Binding not updating XAML but PropertyChanged called

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, synchronization

I am trying to bind the visibility of a WPF UI element in my XAML to a property of my view model (`MainViewModel.DisplayPopup`), which is updated from the property of another view model (`ContactViewModel`) which is a property of this class (`MainViewModel`). The `BaseViewModel` class extends `INotifyPropertyChanged` and uses a Nuget package that **automatically calls the PropertyChanged event inside of each property's setter.**

This is my view model code:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ContactViewModel> TankItems {get; set; }
    public bool DisplayPopup
    {
        get => TankItems.Any(contact => contact.DisplayPopup);
    }
    public MainViewModel() : base()
    {
        TankItems = new ObservableCollection<ContactViewModel>();
        TankItems.Add(new ContactViewModel());
        TankItems.Add(new ContactViewModel());
    }
}

public class ContactViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private bool _isSelected = false;
    public bool DisplayPopup {get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsSelected {get => _isSelected; set { _isSelected = value; DisplayPopup = value;            
}
```

This is my XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TankItems}" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
 <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayPopup}" /> <!-- Stays as false -->
 </Border>
```

What I expect to happen is when I click one of the `ListBox` items, `DisplayPopup` becomes `true`, but it stays the same. HOWEVER, if I log the value of `((MainViewModel)DataContext).DisplayPopup)` I get the correct value - `false` in the beginning then `true` when the selection is changed.

Why is the binding value not updating?

**Update**

Here is the `BaseViewModel`, which uses [Fody PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterfaceAttribute]
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: can you please provide more infos about BaseViewModel? where is the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface implemented? are you using Fody PropertyChanged?

Comment: you can remove AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterfaceAttribute since you used INotifyPropretyChanged for your class. Fody Property Changed injects every class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
Have you tried to raise it manually?

Comment: In DisplayPopup, you specified an expression to compute a value.
This value depends on the values ​​of the items in the TankItems collection and is calculated correctly.
You expect that binding to this property will change the value too.
But this expectation is not true.
To do this, create a PropertyChanged (DisplayPopup) in case of changes in any TankItems.
Your code doesn't do that.
How to do it using FodyPropertyChanged - I don't know.
I am not using this package.

Comment: To spell out what EldHasp is saying in his comment (make it an answer!), you have "a Nuget package that automatically calls the PropertyChanged event inside of each property's setter", but `MainViewModel.DisplayPopup` doesn't have a setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the binding to `DisplayPopup` does not update is that the property is a computed property. A computed property lacks a setter and therefore never raises `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged`. The data binding listens to this event. As the result `DisplayPopup.Get` is only called once (the moment the binding is initialized).

To solve this you can either let the `MainViewModel` listen to `PropertyChanged` events of the `ContactViewModel` items or as it seems that you are interested in selected items simply bind the `ListBox.SelectedItem` and change `MainViewModel.DisplayPopup` on changes.

For simplicity I recommend the second solution.

Note that in order to make the `ListBox.IsSelected` binding work you must set the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` and target `ListBoxItem` instead of `ListBox`:

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ContactViewModel> TankItems { get; set; }
    
    private ContactViewModel selectedTankItem;
    public ContactViewModel SelectedTankItem 
    { 
      get => this.selectedTankItem; 
      set
      {
        this.selectedTankItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.SelectedTankItem));

        this.DisplayPopup = this.SelectedTankItem != null; 
    }

    // Raises INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    public bool DisplayPopup { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel() : base()
    {
        TankItems = new ObservableCollection<ContactViewModel>()
        {
          new ContactViewModel(),
          new ContactViewModel()
        };
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TankItems}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTankItem}">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
              Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ContactViewModel}">
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Test" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Border>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayPopup}" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Also, when I add the DataType attribute, I get this error: `error MC3066: The type reference cannot find a public type named 'ContactViewModel'.`

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to qualify this type using the containing namespace. This is always necessary, whether writing XAML or C#. E.g. `{x:Type main:ContactViewModel}` in case you defined the namespace's XML alias as 'main'. You can leave the data type, but setting it adds Intellisense/Compiletime support, which makes writing the code easier.

Answer (score 1):

### Binding Selected State in Tank Items

There are multiple issues in your code. Let's start with the `ContactViewModel`.

```
public bool IsSelected {get => _isSelected; set { _isSelected = value; DisplayPopup = value;
```

The `DisplayPopup` property is redundant, as it is has the same state as `IsSelected`, remove it.

```
<ListBox.Style>
   <Style TargetType="ListBox">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   </Style>
</ListBox.Style>
```

This XAML is wrong. You have to bind the [`IsSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.isselected?view=netcore-3.1) property of a `ListBoxItem`, not the `ListBox`. Plus you bind to an `IsSelected` property on `MainViewModel`, as this is the `DataContext` here. This property does not exist, so the binding will not work. Instead use an `ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>SelectedTankItem 
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

### Updating the Display Popup Property

You want to set `DisplayPopup` on `MainViewModel` to `true`, if any item is selected. The item container style above will set the `IsSelected` property of your `ContactViewModel`, but it does not automatically trigger a property change of `DisplayPopup` in `MainViewModel`. Hence, the "Text" binding will never update its value.

To solve this, make the `DisplayPopup` property in `MainViewModel` a simple get-set property. You do not need to compute it. Create a second property to bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` in `MainViewModel`. This property will get set, when the selection changes.

```
public bool DisplayPopup { get; set; } 
public ContactViewModel SelectedTankItem { get; set; }
```

Additionally, create a method called `OnSelectedTankItemChanged` where you set the `DisplayPopup` property depending on `SelectedTankItem`. This method will automatically be called by the Fody framework, when `SelectedTankItem` changes.

```
public void OnSelectedTankItemChanged()
{
   DisplayPopup = SelectedTankItem != null;
}
```

Then bind the `SelectedItem` on your `ListBox` to `SelectedTankItem`.

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TankItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTankItem}">
   <!-- ...other code. -->
</ListBox>
```

You can simplify your base view model by removing the property changed code. You do not need it, since the attribute will cause Fody to implement it for you.

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterfaceAttribute]
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
}
```

Comment: Using event callbacks in code-behind to handle view events does not violate MVVM. To replace this handler with an `ICommand` that also executes  its delegate in the same code-behind doesn't add value but complexity. Commands are useful in a MVVM context to let the view execute methods of the view model (as data binding to methods is not allowed in WPF). Instead of implementing e.g. a `Button.Click` handler in the view model, you bind the click source to an `ICommand` implementation.

Comment: In the scenario of reacting to a selected item it would be much easier to bind `Selector.SelectedItem` instead of handling `Selector.SelectionChanged` event. Since the reason for `MainViewModel.DisplaPopup` not to update is that fact that it is implemented as computed property without raisin a change notification, your answer doesn't solve the problem I guess.

Comment: @BionicCode Thank you very much. I cannot believe that I missed the selected item binding... Nevertheless, that solution works, too. The property change notification is raised automatically.